# Equivalent to robocopy on MacOs - Copy full folder structure but with empty files

Tags: bash, macos, robocopy

#### What I want to achieve

I would like to copy the structure of an existing folder including folders and files but I would like the size of the files to be 0. So it would create an empty file, with the same name and extension.

#### Windows

I know how to do it by running : `robocopy source destination /create /e /xc /xn /xo`

#### Question

What is the equivalent command I could use on Mac ?

Comment: You don't mention whether the ownership, permissions and timestamps need to be copied forward to your empty structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a  script that might do what you want.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source=$1
dest=$2

while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  mkdir -p "$dest${file%/*}" || exit
  touch -r "$file" "$dest$file"
done < <(find "$source" -type f -print0)
```

Howto use

```
./myscript source/ destination/
```